# primera y ultima letra de una frase en java, Arreglos?

Tags: java, poo, intellij-idea

Ayuda con este ejercicio

// El usuario va a ingresar una oracion o frase de N caracteres y un separador de palabras. //sistema realice las siguientes acciones: /*1.El sistema debe mantener la primera y ultima letra de la palabras 2.El sistema debe contar y omitir las coincidencias de las letras ya existentes 3.El sistema debe mostrar el resultado final 4.El sistema no debe procesar las palabras que sean menores o igual a 2 caracteres. 5.El sistema debe mantener las caracteres especiales */

introducir el código aquí

"public class Main {" " public static void main(String[] args) {"

```
char caracter;
String frase="";
char primera;
int posFinal;



Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

Utilidades.imprimirMensaje("Ingrese frase o oración");
frase=Utilidades.capturarDatos();


StringTokenizer stWords = new StringTokenizer(frase);

while(stWords.hasMoreTokens()){

    frase = stWords.nextToken();
    System.out.println(frase.substring(0,1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo este ejemplo con comentarios:

```
public String processWords(String sentence, String separator) {

  StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sentence, separator);

  String result = "";

  while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String word = tokenizer.nextToken();

    // guardo la primer y ultima letra
    String firstLetter = word.substring(0, 1);
    String lastLetter = word.substring(word.length() - 1);

    // Cuenta y salta las coincidencias de letras ya existentes en la palabra
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < word.length() - 1; i++) {
      if (word.charAt(i) == firstLetter.charAt(0) || word.charAt(i) == lastLetter.charAt(0)) {
        count++;
      }
    }

    // agrego la palabra procesada al resultado
    result += firstLetter;
    result += count;
    result += lastLetter;
    result += separator;
  }

  return result;
}
```